# run fast api from a class

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

I want to run fastapi from a custom class
it's ok when I pass self.app as first argument to run method, but to use reload=True it is
necessary to use "module:app" pattern
what is the correct app name (string) when it is initialized in a class?

here is a simple file named **main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

class ApiServer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

        @self.app.get("/")
        async def read_root():
            return {"Hello": "World"}

    def run(self):
        # uvicorn.run(self.app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000) #work but i wanna use 
        # reload=True which nedd to pass app in pattern "module:app"
        uvicorn.run("main:self.app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True, use_colors=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = ApiServer()
    server.run()
```

Comment: Interesting thing: just wonder why would you do that? what is the use case?

Comment: I would say server.app but haven’t tested it

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as `uvicorn main:server.app --reload`, but you need to move the definition of `server` out of the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

class ApiServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

        @self.app.get("/")
        async def read_root():
            return {"Hello": "World"}

server = ApiServer()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run()
```

This if because `uvicorn` doesn't run your python file as the main file, so otherwise, `server` (and therefore your FastAPI app) will never get instantiated.

The real question is as jossefaz wrote, think about **why** do you want to do this. As your API grows, the `__init__` method will keep growing and to me, it seems like a hassle to define all your methods two extra indentation levels in. What would be the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

class ApiServer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = FastAPI()

        @self.app.get("/")
        async def read_root():
            return {"Hello": "World"}

    def run(self):
        # uvicorn.run(self.app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000) #work but i wanna use 
        # reload=True which nedd to pass app in pattern "module:app"
        uvicorn.run("main:server.app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True, use_colors=False) 
                 # self.app ->  server.app

server = ApiServer() ### edit here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run()
```